# Predictions from model.predict() not correct

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am using model.predict to predict labels for unseen data in a sentence classification task. But the prediction is always 1 even if I give sentence of opposite label.

Here is the code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

maxlen = 1152  

### PREDICT NEW UNSEEN DATA ###
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
label_enc = LabelEncoder()
label_enc.fit(tar_list)
X_test = ['asdsadav dawd','this is boring', 'wow i like this you did a great job', 'ima cry tht was mean','1 nov 1968 george harrison became the first beatle to release a solo album in the u k with the soundtrack to ']

X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=maxlen)

a = (model.predict(X_test)>0.5).astype(int).ravel()
print(a)

reverse_pred = label_enc.inverse_transform(a.ravel())
print(reverse_pred)
```

And here is the output

```
[1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1]
```

The output of `model.predict(X_test)` is

```
[[0.8882162]
 [0.8882162]
 [0.8882162]
 [0.8882162]
 [0.8882162]]
```

As I can see the first string means absolutely nothing. Still it has got a positive label. Also, the 2nd string is a negative one but it also has a positive label.

Comment: Could you add the output of just `model.predict(X_test)`. Also, are you using any existing model?

Comment: I have added the output of `model.predict(X_test)`. Yes, I am using a sequential model which is trained already.

Comment: This could mean that you model did not learn to do the task it was supposed to learn. Check for signs of overfitting/underfitting in your loss metrics. Your model is outputting the same value over and over again (0.8882162), see if this happens during training too by using some logging mechanism.

Comment: @AndreaAngeli My model is overfitting a little bit but I am using early stopping, so if the accuracy gets constant, the training will stop automatically. However, i did not understand your last sentence regarding logging mechanism.

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I am already using sigmoid in my dense layer. I think that the low epochs are the reason model is not able to learn. I am training my model only for 10 epochs.